# Upload with Register Asp.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to edit default Register method to enable user upload files during registration, in my ASP.NET MVC 5 application. I have edited controller to this :

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, HttpPostedFileBase file1, HttpPostedFileBase file2)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
```

In View I have this :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="AssignmentPath">Assignment: </label>
<div class="col-md-10">
        <input id="AssignmentPath" title="Submit your assignment" type="file" name="file1" />

    </div>
</div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="FontPath">Font : </label>
<div class="col-md-10">
        <input id="FontPath" title="Submit your font" type="file" name="file2" />

    </div>
</div>
```

When I debug code, I see that both file1 and file2 are null in the Controller. Can you tell me what the problem is? Thanks.

Comment: Check Request.Files.Count

Comment: Has your form tag enctype="multipart/form-data"?

Comment: Is your `RegisterViewModel` coming back as null as well? At first blush this looks pretty standard. Maybe include `FormMethod.Post` along with what `tmg` suggested in your `BeginForm()` if it's not already there.

Comment: Try to add "HttpPostedFileBase file1" as properties in RegisterViewModel class. Think that form send data only in first parameter - model.

Comment: @Giraffe A post method can have as many properties as you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your view should be like this

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm ("Index","Home", FormMethod.Post,  
                            new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))  
    {                    
         <input type="file" name="file1" />
         <input type="file" name="file2"/>
         <input type="submit" value="Upload file"/>
    }
```

Comment: Then, can you tell me how I can use `new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }` and `new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }` at the same time? Thank you

Comment: @jason Change the `BeginForm()` to `(Html.BeginForm("Create", "Standard", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "form-horizontal", @role = "form" }))`

Comment: @DrewKennedy it says BeginForm can not take 6 elements.

Comment: @jason I edited the code in my comment. I copy/pasted from a project of mine while forgetting to change the Action and Controller values, so make sure you change those to `Index` and `Home`.